# Use custom localized validation message with object rule

Tags: validation, message, rules, laravel-6

### Problem

According to Laravel docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#localization), i can add in the `custom` section of my `validation.php` file my custom validation error messages, but how should i specify the rule for which the message is for if the rule in my request is an object rule?

#### request

```
return [
    'parent.field' => ['nullable', new ObjcetRule()],
];
```

#### validations.php

```
return [
    // other messages

    'custom' => [
        'field' => [
            'nullable => 'nullable rule custom message',
            '???'     => 'object rule custom message',  // what key should i use here?
        ],
    ],
];
```

#### My specific case

I'm using [BenSampo/laravel-enum](https://github.com/BenSampo/laravel-enum) package for enums, but in the [validations section](https://github.com/BenSampo/laravel-enum#validation) of its doc there is nothing about that.